# Вызвать Xamarin.Forms страницу используя mvvmcross

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

Есть приложение Xamarin + mvvmcross. В приложении есть представление `FirstView` и `FirstViewModel`. Нужно добавить к проекту Xamarin.Forms страницу About, чтобы из FirstView я переходил на общую для android wp iOS страницу About. Как это можно сделать и можно ли вызывать представления на Xamarin.Forms используя mvvmcross?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался! Нужно создать собственный Presentor для каждой из платформ, который будет вызывать то или иное представление (Page или View). Вот этот чувак отлично описал, как это можно сделать

http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю MvvmCross используется больше для нативной разработки, вот статья как на MvvmCross организовать навигацию https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation

А на Xamarin Forms я юзал INavigation https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-navigation-page/